# Set another folder as Desktop on Windows 10

Tags: windows

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/942994/make-another-folder-my-desktop-on-mac)  I would like to have another folder actually store my files that visibly show on my desktop.  The reasoning is I have a large HDD for file storage and a smaller SSD with the OS that I would rather not clutter up with files.

Comment: so you want another desktop? in your desktop?

Comment: Pretty much.  I want a folder on my HDD that I can save files to which will be visible and accessible on my desktop as if they were on the SSD with my operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite easy, and many plenty of people are using difference storage for OS(ex, a M.2, or a SSD) then another storage for basically everything(HDD). You'll just have to read each installation that you'll do.

Your PC setup will basically have a Master and Slave disks, Master is the SSD, which in booting, will be accessed by your CPU for OS information, and your HDD Slave, to store all other clutters.

While installing, you just have to make sure that you don't click next, read everything, and when you reach the point to where will you install the software, choose. After installing, those softwares that you want to access to will have shortcuts in your desktop.

BUT, If your thinking, of replicating EVERYTHING from a folder in your HDD, to your desktop... I guess you could create shortcuts for those files...

Comment: If you're talking about generically installing software and putting shortcuts on the desktop, that's not what I'm trying to do.  Nor do I want to put a shortcut to every file on my HDD on my Desktop.  If you read the question I linked to, you would see that my problem has a solution on Mac, but it is still a complicated one and unfortunately I am not running OS X.  Essentially, I want to add a folder that Windows looks in when it displays my desktop files.

Comment: @Vendea What for?

Comment: a) because it would be more convenient
b) because why not?
c) I want to play God and mangle Windows beyond recognition

Comment: @Vendea how so?

Comment: And actually /why/ I want to do this isn't...terribly relevant to the discussion.  I was just hoping someone might have the answer.  If you don't have the answer you are free to move on to other questions that you do have the answer to.

Comment: a) How convinient is "your" convinient? I can't see any convinience on looking at a folder from your desktop just to see a folder on your storage, I'll just go to my computer, then look in it directly.  b)Then dont because c)You want to complicate a very simple thing, you wanna be God? then research.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out.

When you open up My PC you can right click on Desktop > Properties > Location tab.  The middle button on that tab is a "Move" option which lets you select another folder - in my case one named "Desktop" on my other drive - and then moves anything on your current desktop to the new one and changes the target folder of the desktop.